# angular 2+ events calendar with Hebrew and Jewish dates

Tags: angular, calendar, localization, angular5, hebrew

I need events calendar component to my angular 5 application,

Look like 'Google Calendar' with an option to Hebrew dates and Jewish events.

Does anyone know about such a Calendar?

Answer (score 1):

I am in a similar search...

The only suitable component that I have found so far is [DatePicker from NG Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/calendars#hebrew)

[Hebcal JS](https://github.com/hebcal/hebcal-js) package may be useful as well

Answer (score 0):

I implemented [angular calendar](https://angular-calendar.com/#/kitchen-sink).

1. added "he" to my locale, [like that](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar/issues/431#issuecomment-487901271).
2. set my local to `"he"` for getting the right RTL support. and Hebrew texts for the whole calendar.
3. used [hebcal api](https://www.hebcal.com/home/40/displaying-todays-hebrew-date-on-your-website) to get the dates in Hebrew format for each day.
4. used [this guide](https://angular-calendar.com/#/custom-templates) to edit my components and add the Hebrew date to each day

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who struggling with this issue...I looked for something similar-

I had a calendar from [fullCalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/), and I couldn't choose another library, wasn't important to me the jewish events, more looked for the hebrew dates next to the gregorian in the day's header.
Eventually what I did is the following:

I created two functions: `getHebrewDates` and `setHebrewDates` (they are not getter/setters...)

```js
getHebrewDates(month: number, year:number){
    const currMonth = month.toString().padStart(2,"0");
    //'padStart' is for getting "02" instead of "2"
    const nextMonth = (month + 1).toString().padStart(2,"0");
    const start = `${year}-${currMonth}-01`;
    const end =  `${year}-${nextMonth}-01`;
    const url = `https://www.hebcal.com/converter?cfg=json&start=${start}&end=${end}&g2h=1`;
    
    fetch(url, {method: 'GET'})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setHebewDates(data);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  }
```

as you can see - I use an api url that provided by `Hebcal`, this api gives me the hebrew dates for each day in the range I supplied via the `start` and `end` parameters. see
[Hebcal Api for converting dates h2g and g2h](https://www.hebcal.com/home/219/hebrew-date-converter-rest-api)

next-

```js
setHebewDates(dates:any[]){
  const dayDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("fc-daygrid-day");
  for(let i = 0; i < dayDivs.length; i++){
    const dayDiv = dayDivs.item(i);
    const dayHeader = dayDiv.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;

    const newElement = document.createElement("a");//or whatevet elemtn you want
    newElement.classList.add("hebrewDate");

    //'dayDiv' element has an attribute called 'dataset' that contains 
    //an object with the current date
    let date  = dates["hdates"][dayDiv["dataset"]["date"]]?.heDateParts.d;
    if(date != undefined){
      newElement.innerText = date;
      dayHeader.append(newElement);
    }
  } 
 }
```

Because I don't know any method of fullCalendar that pushes elements into the date-header - I had to use plain js to change the DOM.

Now add the following css styles:

```css
::ng-deep .hebrewDate{
    font-size: 16px;
    padding:4px;
}

::ng-deep .fc-daygrid-day-top{
    justify-content: space-between; 
    /*so the hebrew date will stand to the right and gregorian to the left*/
}
```

and last step - call the `getHebrewDates` from the prev and next callbacks.
retreive the current viewed monthe via `calendar.getDate().getMonth()/getFullYear()

**Note:** You'll get the previous month and not the current (if you're looking at April - you'll get "3") so just add the month `+1`

Comment: in order to avoid fetching delay... You should install the hebcal/core itselft.  `npm install @hebcal/core`  see the [library documentation](https://npm.io/package/@hebcal/core)